# What are the required license for Full-Site In Salesforce1 Browser App?

Tags: community, salesforce1-app

When I paste the URL Of salesforce1 Browser App like http://MyUrl.com/one/one.app,
I am getting below Error,
**Your Salesforce edition or user license isn't supported yet.view Full Site**

Can Any one suggest what kind of license we need for this.Community URL working fine for me.
Please Help me out for this.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the user checkbox "Salesforce1 User" is checked.

Comment: Hi David, Yes I already did It but Still getting this Error.

Answer (score 1):

@yogesh, you mentioned "Community URL" in your question. For the record, you cannot access a community using the native Salesforce1 app just yet. Only the Salesforce1 browser web app is available for communities in Spring '14. You can check the [release notes](https://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_spring14_release_notes.pdf) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem.

I am following the post made by Andreas in...
https://success.salesforce.com/apex/answers?id=90630000000hSSK

This must be domain level problem because we haven't even tried to sign in yet, we have only identified the community domain in the URL.

Do we have to register our domain somewhere else for Salesforce1?